# Logarithmic equation

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I'm studying logarithms and I encountered this equation:
$$[\log_9(k+1)]^2+\log_9(k+1)+(k+1)>3$$
I tried a lot but I still couldn't solve it! I know this may be easy for most of you  but please could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Usually $k$ is used for integers. Is that the case here? If so then you only have to check a few.

Comment: @Yiyuan I edited

Comment: worth a +1 plz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $k \in \mathbb{N}$ you have $\log_9(k+1) > 0.$ Therefore it is obvious that all $k>1$ satisfy the in equality (because $k+1 \ge 3$). For $k=0$ it is obviously wrong, so the only case to check is $k=1$, and here the LHS is $\approx 2.41\dots$.

Summary: The integer solutions are all $k>1$, i.e. $k=2,3, \dots$

Comment: Thanks I actually never thought about that, it was easier then I expected

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see if the solution must be integer or real.
In every case, pose $t=\log_9(k+1)$, then solve $t^2+t+(k-2)>0$, from which
$$
t_{\pm}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4(k-2)}}{2}
\;.$$
So in order to have real solutions we must impose
$k\leq2+\frac{1}{4}$.

Then we have
$$
\left[\log_9(k+1)<\frac{-1-\sqrt{1-4(k-2)}}{2}\right]\vee\left[\log_9(k+1)>\frac{-1+\sqrt{1-4(k-2)}}{2}\right]\;.
$$